# Component did update returning always the same props and state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I found a lot of solutions about this problem but none of them work.

I have a view which renders dynamically components depending on the backend response

```
/**
 * Module dependencies
 */
const React = require('react');
const Head = require('react-declarative-head');

const MY_COMPONENTS = {
  text: require('../components/fields/Description'),
  initiatives: require('../components/fields/Dropdown'),
  vuln: require('../components/fields/Dropdown'),
  severities: require('../components/fields/Dropdown'),
};

const request = restclient({
  timeout: 5000,
  baseURL: '/api',
});

const { DropdownItem } = Dropdown;

class CreateView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal: false,
      states: props.states,
      error: props.error,
      spinner: true,
      state: props.state,
      prevState: '',
      components: [],
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.getRequiredFields = this.getRequiredFields.bind(this);
    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);
    this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
    this.loadComponents = this.loadComponents.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadComponents();
  }


  onChangeHandler(event, value) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      prevState.prevState = prevState.state;
      prevState.state = value;
      prevState.spinner = true;
      return prevState;
    }, () => {
      this.getRequiredFields();
    });
  }

  getRequiredFields() {
    request.get('/transitions/fields', {
      params: {
        to: this.state.state,
        from: this.state.prevState,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        const pComponents = this.state.components.map(c => Object.assign({}, c));
        pComponents.forEach((c) => {
          c.field.required = 0;
          c.field.show = false;
        });
        response.data.forEach((r) => {
          const ob = pComponents.find(c => c.field.name === r.name);
          if (ob) {
            ob.field.required = r.required;
            ob.field.show = true;
          }
        });
        this.setState({
          components: pComponents,
          fields: response.data,
          spinner: false,
        });
      })
      .catch(err => err);
  }

  loadComponents() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      prevState.components = Object.keys(MY_COMPONENTS).map((k) => {
        const field = {
          name: k,
          required: 0,
          show: true,
        };
        return {
          field, component: MY_COMPONENTS[k],
        };
      });
      return prevState;
    });
  }

  handleChange(field, value) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      prevState[field] = value;
      return prevState;
    });
  }

  changeState(field, value) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      prevState[`${field}`] = value;
      return prevState;
    });
  }

  render() {
    const Components = this.state.components;

    return (
      <Page name="CI" state={this.props} Components={Components}>
        <Script src="vendor.js" />
        <Card className="">
            <div className="">
              <div className="">
                <Spinner
                  show={this.state.spinner}
                />
                {Components.map((component, i) => {
                  const Comp = component.component;
                  return (<Comp
                    key={i}
                    value={this.state[component.field.name]}
                    field={component.field}
                    handleChange={this.handleChange}
                    modal={this.state.modal}
                    changeState={this.changeState}
                  />);
                })
                }
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Card>

      </Page>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = CreateView;
```

and the dropdown component

```
const React = require('react');

const request = restclient({
  timeout: 5000,
  baseURL: '/api',
});

const { DropdownItem } = Dropdown;

class DrpDwn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      field: props.field,
      values: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    console.log('state', this.state.field);
    console.log('prevState', prevState.field);
    console.log('prevProps', prevProps.field);
    console.log('props', this.props.field);
  }

  render() {
    const { show } = this.props.field;
    return (show && (
      <div className="">
        <Dropdown
          className=""
          onChange={(e, v) => this.props.handleChange(this.props.field.name, v)}
          label={this.state.field.name.replace(/^./,
            str => str.toUpperCase())}
          name={this.state.field.name}
          type="form"
          value={this.props.value}
          width={100}
          position
        >
          {this.state.values.map(value => (<DropdownItem
            key={value.id}
            value={value.name}
            primary={value.name.replace(/^./, str => str.toUpperCase())}
          />))
          }
        </Dropdown>
      </div>
    ));
  }

module.exports = DrpDwn;
```

The code actually works, it hide or show the components correctly but the thing is that i can't do anything inside `componentdidupdate` because the `prevProps` `prevState` and `props` are always the same.

I think the problem is that I'm mutating always the same object, but I could not find the way to do it.

What I have to do there is to fill the dropdown item.

Ps: The "real" code works, i adapt it in order to post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React state is supposed to be immutable. Since you're mutating state, you break the ability to tell whether the state has changed. In particular, i think this is the main spot causing your problem:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  prevState.components = Object.keys(MY_COMPONENTS).map((k) => {
    const field = {
      name: k,
      required: 0,
      show: true,
    };     return {
      field, component: MY_COMPONENTS[k],
    };
  });
  return prevState;
});
```

You mutate the previous states to changes its components property. Instead, create a new state:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  const components = Object.keys(MY_COMPONENTS).map((k) => {
    const field = {
      name: k,
      required: 0,
      show: true,
    };
    return {
      field, component: MY_COMPONENTS[k],
    };
  });
  return { components }
}
```

You have an additional place where you're mutating state. I don't know if it's causing your particular problem, but it's worth mentioning anyway:

```
const pComponents = [].concat(this.state.components);
// const pComponents = [...this.state.components];
pComponents.forEach((c) => {
  c.field.required = 0;
  c.field.show = false;
});
response.data.forEach((r) => {
  const ob = pComponents.find(c => c.field.name === r.name);
  if (ob) {
    ob.field.required = r.required;
    ob.field.show = true;
  }
});
```

You do at make a copy of state.components, but this will only be a shallow copy. The array is a new array, but the objects inside the array are the old objects. So when you set ob.field.required, you are mutating the old state as well as the new.

If you want to change properties in the objects, you need to copy those objects at every level you're making a change. The spread syntax is usually the most succinct way to do this:

```
let pComponents = this.state.components.map(c => {
  return {
    ...c,
    field: {
      ...c.field,
      required: 0,
      show: false
    }
  }
});

response.data.forEach(r => {
  const ob = pComponents.find(c => c.field.name === r.name);
  if (ob) {
    // Here it's ok to mutate, but only because i already did the copying in the code above
    ob.field.required = r.required;
    ob.field.show = true;
  }
})
```

Comment: The first thing that you mention is correct, I didn't realize what I was doing but is not the solution to my problem yet. 
When you talk about the shallow copy, i was looking for something like `Object.assing`, Should I do it first for each component?? Ty for the help.

Comment: I modify by cloning the state object, but still not working.

Comment: Object.assign is a shallow copy as well. Whether you choose to use object.assign or the spread syntax, you'll need to repeat the process at every level that you make a change. I've edited in an example.